# Kendo Grid Grouping column sorting is not working

Tags: asp.net, kendo-grid

In Kendo UI Grid, After grouping grouped column sorting is not working, remaining column sorting is working fine.

Can anyone give me idea on how to sort grouped column from client side.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

When you group your data in kendo grid it automatically sort groups asc. 
You can read about this behavior in [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-group.dir)

But what you need is change group sorting on column header click.

on `dataBound` event try to look at grid [`dataSource.sort()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#methods-sort) collection and if need change group sorting direction.

Something like this:

```
//Get the grid object
 var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
// Get the datasource bound to the grid
var ds = grid.dataSource;
// Get current sorting
var sort = ds.sort();
// Display sorting fields and direction
if (sort) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
        if(sort[i].field == " myField"){
           grid.dataSource.group({field:"myField", dir: sort[i].dir });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kendo UI Grid Grouping gives you `ListSortDirection.Ascending` sorting by default. If you want to do something else you have to set it. If you are using the WebApi interface and generating a kendoRequest for the `Kendo.mvc.dll` method `.ToDataSourceResult(kendoRequest);` then you may try something like this:

```
var sort = kendoRequest.Sorts.FirstOrDefault();
var group = kendoRequest.Groups.FirstOrDefault(); 
if(sort != null && group != null) {
   if(sort.Member == group.Member && sort.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Descending) {
      kendoRequest.Groups[0].SortDirection = sort.SortDirection;
   }
}
var result = data.ToDataSourceResult(kendoRequest);
```